# Hosting Web Application ASP.NET MVC on Local Machine Without Internet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting, web-hosting

I built my first MVC ASP.Net web Application and host it on IIS on my machine and it works fine.Now i want to host it on Client Computer without internet. Please guide my how can i perform this.
Do i Need to Install Visual Studio and SQL server on my Client Computer as well and then publish it there, or
I can simply copy the published Folder and copy to client Machine which i don't know how.
Moreover how would i manage my DB on Client Computer and what necessary changes should i Make in Web.config file to work it properly. 
Thank u.

Comment: what's the point of a web application with no internet? Yeah you could install IIS and SQL Server on each machine (Visual Studio is only for the programmer) and create lots of completely isolated, disconnected copies of the application with their own datastore. Just to check, is that actually the desired outcome or should the database be shared by multiple users so they can collaborate? An app with its own separate local database is very unusual in the last 20 years. A web app installed locally on different machines is also a bit odd, normally you'd make a desktop Forms app for that.

Comment: Its Inventory based application and clients have small business now. Each Application will be given to new client. so In future when their business expand, app will be host to live server, for their multi branches.

Comment: @ADyson Can u please tell me how to publish it in client's computer. and what changes should i make in web.config file

Comment: Ok I see. I thought you meant "client" in the technical sense as in a user's PC. If you don't have internet access to the client's computer then you have to go on-site and install it onto the server from a disk. Or you get the client to download it and provide them some install instructions. But for a small business market you might be better off providing a SAAS style solution online in the cloud, where the user just logs into your URL and creates an account which they pay rent for.

Comment: Then you don't have to worry about the business having the correct infrastructure to support your app such as a suitable server, sufficient capacity, backup policies etc etc etc.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson i saved it for Future. but would u please tell me how can install this on single machine of my customer.

Comment: Make sure the target machine has IIS and the correct version of SQL Server installed (and they have the correct license, unless you're using SQL express). Then...you have to publish your website to your local filesystem somewhere, and take that published copy and move it to the client's machine (either by remote access or USB disk or whatever means they provide). You also have to make backup file of your SQL database (or export it as a SQL script) which you then install into the target machine's SQL instance. And then you think about how you do an upgrade later

Comment: In future, it would be prudent to consider how you're going to actually deploy the application and what the best mode of delivery will be (e.g. on-site vs SAAS, and how you can best install with least effort) _before_ designing and building your application - then this consideration becomes part of the design process.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. I ll Keep in mind your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following Steps.

1 ) Create a folder in `C:\inetpub\YourFolder`

2 ) Place your Published Web Application here.

3 ) Open `Internet Information Service`.

4 ) Sites -> Add Website

5 ) Give a site name

6 ) Set above folder path as at Physical Path Option

7 ) Select a Port no as example 88

8 ) Press OK

**Image**

[image: IIs Manager]

9 ) Run in browser

while running, it may show an error, that Login failed for `IIS APPPOOL\my-website-name` , to clear this problem do the following steps more :

1. Open MSSQL Server.
2. Open security folder -> Logins folder then right click, and select New Login from option.

[image: MS SQL Server]

3. Add the name as shown in image.

[image: Add new login]

4. Select `user mapping` tab, then select database file from the list. Then select the check box for `db_owner` and `public`.
5. Run in browser.

[image: User Mapping]

For more details : [Asp.Net MVC website hosting in localhost](https://youtu.be/3SXBi3zd-OM)

Comment: Ok @Alsamil Mehboob. Let Me try it.

Comment: what about the database?

Comment: Thanks @Alsamil Mehboob. It does Work.

Comment: @ADyson , now the answer updated with database section.

Comment: I think actually they were asking about _installing_ SQL Server, not just creating a new user. And I wouldn't give a web application db_owner privileges - it's safer only to give it the permissions it actually needs. It's very unlikely it needs full control of the database (e.g. to create and delete tables, for example). If there turns out to be any kind of security problem with the application, then the database is much more vulnerable to attack if the application has too many privileges.

Answer (score -2):

You can definitely self host a .NET web application using OWIN. Unfortunately documentation and information about it is vague and confusing at best. The fact that you're using MVC makes it somewhat easier as you may be able to directly use the self-host packages from Nuget for self hosting Web API. There may be similar packages for MVC.

I don't have recent experience but a Nuget search for "MVC Self Host" should yield some results.

Below is a link with an example. But the term you are looking for is definitely "self host". It can be done via a console window or (more complex) a windows service. It will likely use some form of OWIN but you can probably find some startup code to copy and paste into your project, usually in the form of a Startup.cs file.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-owin-hosting-and-self-hosting-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: ASP.NET does not run natively in Apache or Nginx (only Mono-compatible code does, which has limitations, or ASP.NET Core which is brand new and OP hasn't mentioned using it) - and why suggest OP to switch to mysql when the solution is already developed in SQL Server? Also saying one webserver is number 1 or number 2 is totally subjective judgement and a discussion of different webservers has no relevance to the question at hand. If I didn't know that Apache and nginx were open source, I'd say this was written as a sales pitch

Comment: i modified now you can check it

Comment: you can host using owin

Comment: This edit is better, although using IIS is still a simpler option, but the question is also about deploying the SQL database