# How to host my MVC project on my own machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, visual-studio, iis, publish

So here's the deal. I created a MVC project which i worked on for a lot of time and everything seems great with it. When i run it from VS itself it works great. 
Now the deal is that i want to publish this project to IIS, and i also want it to be accessed from my IPv4 address and not only from localhost. I moved on half of the internet and i couldn't find a way to do this. Can some one help me with those steps?
1.Publish MVC projects to IIS and access it from my local machine.
2.Access the web with my IPv4 addrees from another computer in the same network.

BTW Working on VS2017

Comment: I cannot believe that half of the internet you searched does not include http://docs.Microsoft.com

Comment: You can refer this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921159/hosting-web-application-asp-net-mvc-on-local-machine-without-internet/48921699#48921699

Answer (score 1):

Create site in IIS. Right click it then edit bindings. Then add one for your local machine and another one for network access.
For your local use:

```
type: "http"
Host Name: "YourName.local"
Port: 80
IP Address: *
```

For your LAN change Ip Address to the IP of the hosting machine and leave the name blank.

Also you will need to modify your hosts file to point to your site from the hosting machine. 
Go to

> Windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

and add: "YourIP"  "YourName.local" or use local host IP for example:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.local
```